# Get top-level directory from makefile variable

Tags: make

What is the simplest code to get the top-level directory part of a makefile variable? Example:

```
BUILD_DIR = dir/subdir/.../sub-a-dub-dir
distclean:
        rm -rf <some code which evaluates to "dir" from $(BUILD_DIR)>
```

PS: I don't mean `$(dir $(dir $(BUILD_DIR)))`, but something which gets the first directory part of *any* variable value.

Comment: `dirname /tmp/foo/bar` will give `/tmp` or `dirname foo/bar/baz` will give `foo`

Comment: @greenmang0: Flagged your answer. First, it's plain wrong (did you even execute those commands?), and second it's for a **makefile**, not Bash.

Comment: @l0b0 It's a comment, and "it's wrong" isn't a good reason to flag anything, just leave a comment saying what the problem is

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I flagged it "not constructive / off topic", both of which applies to it.

Comment: I don't understand your question: what do you mean by “the top-level directory part”? Do you mean the part before the first `/`? Do you guarantee that the argument is a relative path? Are you assuming GNU make?

Comment: @Gilles: To be overly specific, I'd like **the first non-empty substring which does not contain a slash**. I am not "assuming" a specific make, but I am using GNU Make 3.81.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the first component of the directory? If so, turn the path into a list of components, then extract the first component. I assume you're using GNU make, and you're not doing something insane like expect file names with whitespace to go through unscathed. Don't try this with an absolute path.

```
override BUILD_DIR = dir/subdir/.../sub-a-dub-dir
distclean:
        rm -rf $(firstword $(subst /, ,$(BUILD_DIR)))
```

I make `BUILD_DIR` override whatever the user might have passed on the command line, to avoid someone accidentally passing it and having something unintended deleted.

Comment: `BUILD_DIR` was supposed to be an internal variable, but you're right, there's still the possibility that someone sets it to something dangerous. So accepting this answer, with the caveat that *the solution should not be used* :)

Comment: @l0b0 Since we're assuming GNU make: `override BUILD_DIR = …`

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that BUILD_DIR will never start with a '/':

```
rootdir=$( echo $BUILD_DIR | cut -d/ -f1 )
```

Otherwise, you might need to account for paths that start with '/':

```
if [[ $BUILD_DIR =~ "^/" ]]; then
        rootdir=$( echo $BUILD_DIR | cut -d/ -f1,2 )
else
        rootdir=$( echo $BUILD_DIR | cut -d/ -f1 )
fi

echo $rootdir
```

Or maybe it's best to ignore any path that starts with '/'.

Comment: This is for a makefile, **not** Bash. This is a trivial problem in Bash, but I'm interested in a simple **makefile** solution.

Comment: One thing you can do in a Makefile is run commands.  So you create a shell script, in your path, called rootdir, and in your makefile, run "rm -rf $(rootdir $BUILD_DIR)", or something like that.  Or you'll have to do something like pre-define the build root, so that you can `rm -rf` it later.  I would definitely doublecheck the response that the `rootdir` script can pass back, so you don't end up with a syntax error giving your script `rm -rf /`.